# SQL: splitting up WITH statements into read-only tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a project in SQLite where several INSERT statements involve recursive WITH statements.  These INSERT statements are within triggers that are watching for INSERT statements being called on other databases.

I've found that this leads to the recalculation of lots of values every time the WITH statement is triggered, and rather than introduce logic into the WITH statement to only recalculate values that need to be recalculated (which creates sprawl and is difficult for me to maintain), I'd rather take some of the temporary views defined in the WITH statement and make them permanent tables that cache values. I'd then chain triggers so that an update of table_1 leads to an update of table_2, which leads to an update of table_3, etc..  This makes the code easier to debug and maintain.

The issue is that, in the project, I want to make a clear distinction between tables that are user editable and those that are meant for caching intermediary values.  One way to do this is (perhaps) to make the "caching" tables read-only EXCEPT when called via certain triggers.  I've seen a few questions about similar issues in other dialects of SQL but nothing pertaining to SQLite and nothing looking to solve this problem, thus the new question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: SQLite does not have permissions. How foolproof do you want to be?

Comment: Currently, I am using a naming convention that names these intermediary tables with leading underscores, and there is a README, so there have been no issues so far, but I'd like some type of built-in enforcement in the SQL itself.  It'll help make code contributions from third parties easier.